# Show that the following linear transformation is normal.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that if $\|Ax\|=\|A^{*}x\|$ for all $x$ beloging to the finite-dimensional inner product space $X$, the linar transformation $A$ is normal.

Comment: Regarding your answer: in fact, if you're working over a complex vector space, then $(x,Ax) = 0$ for all $x$ if and only if $A = 0$, regardless of whether $A$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 2):

> As $\|Ax\|=\|A^{*}x\|,~\forall x\in X\Rightarrow \|Ax\|^{2}=\|A^{*}x\|^{2},
>          ~\forall x\in X $ or just 
>            \begin{eqnarray*}
>             (Ax,Ax) = (A^{*}x,A^{*}x)\Rightarrow(x,A^{*}Ax)=(x,AA^{*}x) \\
>             \Rightarrow (x,(A^{*}A-AA^{*})x)=0,~\forall x\in X
>          \end{eqnarray*}
>            then all we have to show is that $A^{*}A-AA^{*}=0$, fist note that it is 
>            self-adjoint
>            Lemma:  If $B:X\rightarrow X$ is self-adjoint and 
>            $(x,Ax)=0,~\forall x\in X$, then $A\equiv0$.
>            proof:  just using the hypotheses 
>            \begin{eqnarray*}
>             0&=&(x+y,A(x+y))=(x,Ax)+(x,Ay)+(y,Ax)+(y,Ay)\\
>             &=&(x,Ay)+(y,Ax)=(x,Ay)+(\overline{Ax,y})=(x,Ay)+(\overline{x,A^{*}y})\\
>             &=&(x,Ay)+(\overline{x,Ay}),~\forall x,y \in X
>          \end{eqnarray*}
>            when we take $x=Ay$ we get $0=2\|Ay\|^{2},~\forall y\in X$ so follows that 
>            $A\equiv0$ and then $A^{*}A-AA^{*}=0$ as we wish.